# Git post-receive does not work for me

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I have been through many many many answers but nothing is giving any results.

Basically post-receive is never being called. This is the script inside /home/git/repo.git/hooks/post-receive

```
#!/bin/sh
2>&1 > "post-receive.log"
cd /home/ubuntu/project
git checkout -f master
```

We want to check out to /home/ubuntu/project

There is an Ubuntu server with a user called *ubuntu*. There is also a user called *git*. We clone/push/pull etc against a repository under the git user.

**sudo chmod +x post-receive** is done.

The git user is a sudoer.

So when there is a push **with changes!** nothing happens. post-receive.log is not even created. I can run the script manually on the server as the git user. Not as the Ubuntu user...

Comment: You say you can't run the script (even manually) as the other user.  If you have selinux stuff turned on, is that getting in the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-created the repo using just the Ubuntu user. Not sure what might have been going on with the Git user, you may have been right, torek.

For those who are facing a similar issue and are using a different user account for Git then try the following tutorial - all under the one user.

http://caiustheory.com/automatically-deploying-website-from-remote-git-repository

However please note we had to set the core.worktree **after** the core.bare configuration.